# How to set variable time seconds precision format in .net?

Tags: c#, .net

I am parsing date time field from an excel file. Previously data being dumped into the excel was in format

> 19/12/2018 17:35:18:3415659

Recently, one of our utility is dumping data in format below with less precision

> 19/12/2018 17:35:18:341565

My sample code to parse this date time column from excel is

`var date2 = DateTime.ParseExact(rawDate2, "dd/MM/yyyy HH:mm:ss:fffffff", null);`

How can I handle both scenarios with correct date time parsed everytime?

Comment: Focus on how that utility turns the datetime back into a readable string.

Comment: Thanks @it Parse() didn't worked. Secondly, Excel contains thousands of fields. Not a good idea to switch for every field.

Comment: Use `FFFFFFF` instead of `fffffff` to take *up to* 7 digits. Read [Custom date and time format strings](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/base-types/custom-date-and-time-format-strings).

Comment: @madreflection You should add that as an answer, along with a link to documentation that explains it.

Comment: Can you `.ParseExact(rawDate2, "dd/MM/yyyy HH:mm:ss:g", null)`?

Comment: @JoelCoehoorn: The documentation doesn't speak of parsing, only formatting with the implication that it's bidirectional. I confirmed it by testing it, though.

Comment: @madreflection if it works, you should undelete your answer. It's a better option than mine.

Comment: @JAlex: For date/time values, the `g` format specifier is the Era, e.g. `"A.D."`. The `f` format specifier here has nothing to do with floating-point parsing.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's an overload for ParseExact() that [accepts an array of allowed formats](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.datetime.parseexact?view=netcore-3.1#System_DateTime_ParseExact_System_String_System_String___System_IFormatProvider_System_Globalization_DateTimeStyles_). You can use it to do this:

```
string[] formats = {"dd/MM/yyyy HH:mm:ss:fffffff", "dd/MM/yyyy HH:mm:ss:ffffff"};
var date2 = DateTime.ParseExact(rawDate2, formats, null, DateTimeStyles.None);
```

Alternatively, you can look at the number of characters following the last `:` and append `0`s to pad it out if needed.

Answer (score 1):

According to [Custom date and time format strings](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/base-types/custom-date-and-time-format-strings#FFFFFFF_Specifier), the `F` (uppercase) format specifier will format/parse up to the number of digits of fractional seconds you specify.

> The "FFFFFFF" custom format specifier represents the seven most significant digits of the seconds fraction; that is, it represents the ten millionths of a second in a date and time value. However, trailing zeros or seven zero digits aren't displayed.

It says "displayed" but it also applies to what it parses.

Try this:

```cs
var date2 = DateTime.ParseExact(rawDate2, "dd/MM/yyyy HH:mm:ss:FFFFFFF", null);
```

Comment: When I asked for a link to the documentation, I was hoping to see the "up to" part. The basic custom date and time format documentation page only shows this for output, and even then only if you very carefully compare examples.